# A question about the argument types to the comp predicate in std::lower_bound

Tags: c++, c++11, types, predicate, lower-bound

Reference: [std::lower_bound](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound)

Excerpt:

> `comp` -  binary predicate which returns ​true if the first argument is less than (i.e. is ordered before) the second.
>
> The signature of the predicate function should be equivalent to the following:
>
> ```cpp
> bool pred(const Type1 &a, const Type2 &b);
> ```
>
> While the signature does not need to have `const &`, the function must not modify the objects passed to it and must be able to accept all values of type (possibly `const`) `Type1` and `Type2` regardless of value category (thus, `Type1 &` is not allowed, nor is `Type1` unless for `Type1` a move is equivalent to a copy (since C++11)).

What I would like to clarify in the above excerpt with respect to the type mandate is the following:

> nor is `Type1` unless for `Type1` a move is equivalent to a copy (since C++11)

I presume `Type1&` is not allowed as that could potentially allow the predicate to modify the objects passed in; but why is `Type1` not allowed? Is it only due to optimization, taking cues from the precondition that `Type1` is allowed if a move is equivalent to copy? Or is there more to it than that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Type1&` is not allowed because as the description says, the function must accepts values of all value categories.
A non-const lvalue reference can only bind to lvalues, not to xvalues or prvalues.
For example:

```cpp
void take(int&);
void take_const(const int&);
void take_value(int);

int main() {
    int x;
    take(x); // OK, can accept lvalues
    take(std::move(x)); // error, lvalue reference cannot bind to xvalues
    take(0); // error, lvalue reference cannot bind to prvalues

    take_const(x); // OK
    take_const(std::move(x)); // OK
    take_const(0); // OK, performs temporary materialization

    take_value(x); // OK
    take_value(std::move(x)); // OK, move is equivalent to copy for int
    take_value(0); // OK
}
```

`Type1` is allowed because it satisifes the requirement; you can pass any value category to it. Also, if an lvalue is passed to it, then it performs a copy, which makes it easy to ensure that it doesn't modify the original.

Answer (score 0):

> but why is `Type1` not allowed? Is it only due to optimization, taking
> cues from the precondition that `Type1` is allowed if a move is
> equivalent to copy? Or is there more to it than that?

It is the same reason as with the non-const lvalue, it is not allowed to modify the original. The iterator (see [std::move_iterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/move_iterator)) could return an rvalue reference, which would then be consumed if `Type1` has a move constructor that does something different than its copy constructor.

This could lead to all compared elements ending up empty. Not good! :-)